# Sending multiple emails with different attachments based on list in csv file

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I tried looking for similar Python problems, but I can't find the answer anywhere.  Other solutions are different than what I'm trying to accomplish here.

I have a list of different recipients, and each is receiving different files in outlook.  Some recipients receive more than 1 attachment. I created a csv list with recipient email address and file name.  For example:

[image: Recipient_List.csv]

I have the following code to look up recipient list and send emails to correct receivers, but the code is only recognizing the first row.

```
import glob
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd

for file in glob.glob("*Recipient_List.csv"):
    email_list = pd.read_csv(file)
    emails = email_list['EmailAddress']
    attachments = email_list['AttachmentName']
    PATH = "P:\\this is a path where attachments are located\\"
    email_list.head()

for i in range(len(emails)):
    print("Sending email with " + file)
    print(emails[i])
    email = emails[i]
    attachment = attachments[i]
    attachment1 = PATH + attachment
    with open(attachment1, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as my_attachment:
        myfile = my_attachment.read()
    

        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = email
        mail.Subject = 'Email Subject Name'
        #mail.Body = 'Hello ' + name
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
        mail.display()
        mail.Send()
        break
```

Comment: Can you remove `break` from the second `for` loop?

Comment: removing a break corrected my problem!   it works now.  Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know how this code could be modified to attach a second attachment to same email?  For example, abc@yahoo.com would have 2 attachments to add: RPT_SOMETHING_MTD_SUMMARY.xlsx and RPT_SOMETHING_MTD_DETAIL.xlsx;  How this could be accomplished?